# How to make div centered with keyframe animation even when window is resized

Tags: html, css, keyframe

So I have a question that I can't seem to figure out. I checked out a post on on stack overflow with the same question but there was no answer to it.

Edit: My goal is to make the div centered even when I resize the window. Basically, I want the div to be centered both vertically and horizontally.

My question is how can I make my div centered when using keyframe animations. Here is my code:

```css
#text-1 {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

#text-2 {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

#text-3 {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  8.3% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8.3%,
  25% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33%,
  100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  41.63%,
  58.29% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.66%,
  100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
  66.66% {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  74.96%,
  91.62% {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#text-1 {
 animation-name: anim-1;
}

#text-2 {
 animation-name: anim-2;
}

#text-3 {
 animation-name: anim-3;
}
```

```html
<div class="text" id="text-1">
  <div class="title">
    <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text" id="text-2">
  <div class="title">
    <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text" id="text-3">
  <div class="title">
    <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do exactly and what you mean by `make my div centered`.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I want the div to be centered in the middle of the page. I want it to be centered both vertically and horizontally even when the window is resized. In other words, I want it to be responsive.

Comment: And what are you trying to do with the animation?

Comment: how does that animation centre it - it goes left 110%

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I edited my post to make it more clear. There are three divs, each div will slide in from the left and will stay in the center for a couple of seconds. Here is a codepen. https://codepen.io/nucliweb/pen/ymedj

Comment: @Pete That is the only way I know how to center it.

Comment: @OmarDajani Thanks, that Codepen helped to clarify what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in the simplest manner, I would recommend using flex centering on your parent, then set the children to `position: absolute`. This will allow them to be both always centered vertically and horizontally on the page as well as sit on top of one another (this is important to avoid having the text on different lines).

To do the animation, I would recommend using `transform: translateX();` as this won't affect other elements and will allow you to base all movement off of the initial position of your element. You can also use `animation-delay` to limit the amount of animations you have to make.

This may need some adjustments for browsers other than Chrome, but gives you the initial idea.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  animation-name: slide-in-out;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

#text-1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

#text-2 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

#text-3 {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes slide-in-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="text" id="text-1">
    <div class="title">
      <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text-2">
    <div class="title">
      <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text-3">
    <div class="title">
      <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to have the animations repeat infinitely, you will have to include the 3 different animations and avoid using `animation-delay`.

It's a bit hard to explain, but basically in this case you have to have time for the text entering the frame, staying in the frame, and leaving the frame. Each section of the animation will have to be the same percentage of the overall animation for each section.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

#text-1 {
  animation-name: slide-in-out-1;
}

#text-2 {
  animation-name: slide-in-out-2;
}

#text-3 {
  animation-name: slide-in-out-3;
}

@keyframes slide-in-out-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10%,
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-out-2 {
  0%,
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40%,
  50% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-out-3 {
  0%,
  60% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70%,
  80% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="text" id="text-1">
    <div class="title">
      <p>LEARN TO CODE 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text-2">
    <div class="title">
      <p>LEARN TO CODE 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text-3">
    <div class="title">
      <p>LEARN TO CODE 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chase! :)

Comment: No problem :) Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I do have one question. The text divs keep piling on top of each other. What I mean by this, div (#text-1) displays fine, but when text-2 is displayed both text-1 and text-2 are visible and are overlapping each other. And same with text-3, when text-3 is visible so is text-1 and text-2

Comment: I also need the animations to loop so that it never stops, sorry about all the trouble.

Comment: I actually solved the first problem :) I'm just trying to figure out the loop part now.

Comment: It's no trouble. I went ahead and added a second section to the post regarding repeating animations.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're truly a lifesaver! So if I wanted to change the amount of time each text div is displayed on the screen I just change the animation-duration? :)

Comment: @OmarDajani Exactly! However, if you want to change the percentage of time it takes to enter and leave the screen, you’ll have to change the actual animation percentages.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so, so much again! I really cannot thank you enough! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give your element a `width`. Then you could get the half of the screen with `50vw`. From the half of the screen you would need to subtract the half width of your element. To do this, you could use `calc()`.

```css
#text-1 {
  position: relative;
  animation: anim-1 5s infinite;
  width: 200px
}

#text-2 {
  position: relative;
  animation: anim-2 5s infinite;
  width: 200px;
}

#text-3 {
  position: relative;
  animation: anim-3 5s infinite;
  width: 200px; 
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%, 8.3% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: calc(50vw - 100px); opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
    0%, 33.33% { left: 0; opacity: 0; }
  41.63%, 58.29% { left: calc(50vw - 100px); opacity: 1; }
  66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  74.96%, 91.62% { left: calc(50vw - 100px); opacity: 1; }
  100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="text" id="text-1">
  <div class="title">
     <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text" id="text-2">
  <div class="title">
     <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text" id="text-3">
  <div class="title">
     <p>LEARN TO CODE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question. When I resize the window the div won't be centered. In other words its not responsive.